# Cannot post score with Facebook SDK and Unity

Tags: c#, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine

I am using the Facebook SDK for Unity v5.1.

I successfully login with my facebook account on my android device, and I can post news feed to the timeline, but I cannot post a score. I am using the code from
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/unity/unity-tutorial

```
public void ShareScore() {
    if (FB.IsLoggedIn) {
        var query = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        query["score"] = score.ToString();
        FB.API("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, delegate(FBResult r) { Debug.Log("Result: " + r.Text); }, query);
    }
}
```

I check the logcat it said

```
E/Unity   (29987): You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
E/Unity   (29987): java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/me/scores
```

I have granted publish_actions permission.

What's the problem? Thanks